# Want to write trigger on object to update the picklist field

Tags: apex, trigger, picklist, field-update

```
Class : MonsterPositionClass
Field : Experience__c 
Field : Position__c (picklist )> ( values:'Jr Engineer', 'Team Lead')
Condition : if(Experience__c  >= 7 ) then Team Lead should be shown
```

my code:
// Trigger

```
trigger MonsterPositionTrigger on Monster_Com_JobForm__c (Before Insert, Before Update) {

if(Trigger.isBefore==True && Trigger.isInsert==True) {
   MonsterPositionClass.MonsterpositionFunction(Trigger.new);
}

}
```

// Apex class

```
public class MonsterPositionClass {

    public static void MonsterpositionFunction(list<Monster_Com_JobForm__c> VarMonsterlist){

        for(Monster_Com_JobForm__c VarTemp:VarMonsterlist ){

            string VarPL = VarTemp.Position__c();
            if(VarTemp.Experience__c >=7){

                VarTemp.VarPL='Sr Manager';
            }
            else{
                VarPL='Team Lead';
            }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
for(Monster_Com_JobForm__c VarTemp : VarMonsterlist) {
    if(VarTemp.Experience__c >= 7){
        VarTemp.Position__c='Sr Manager';
    } else {
        VarTemp.Position__c='Team Lead';
    }
}
```

I would strongly advise going through [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/force_com_dev_beginner) modules on [triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers?trail_id=force_com_dev_beginner) as they can help you learn the correct syntax and how to write basic triggers like this one.

Answer (score 1):

**I would say, in the context that this is the only thing being done, this can be set via Workflow field update, or process builder, instead of a trigger which is a much better option. When possible always clicks over code...**

Few things:

1. You are setting the value of the local variable in the else and not the value on the record
2. I do not get where your Position() function is at or what it is supposed to do so I am going to assume you are trying to say it is a field on your object and if so you are referencing it incorrectly

This should fix it, at least it will set the value on the record:

```
public class MonsterPositionClass {

    public static void MonsterpositionFunction(list<Monster_Com_JobForm__c> VarMonsterlist){

        for(Monster_Com_JobForm__c VarTemp:VarMonsterlist ){
            //Since it is a before trigger you can set the field on the record directly.
            if(VarTemp.Experience__c >=7){
                VarTemp.Position__c ='Sr Manager';
            }
            else{
                VarTemp.Position__c ='Team Lead';
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , the issue has been fixed